# base duplicada, escolher aleatorio SQL

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sql-server, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

bom dia grupo, tudo joia?

Estou fazendo um select simples em uma base de clientes e um join em outra base de agentes de telemarketing e me retorta dados duplicados, pois na base de telemarketing possuí mais de 1 atendente.

Eu consigo fazer join e retornar o atendente aleatório / sorteio?

```
  select distinct a.*, 
         b.ag_tlmk 
    from LOJA_TB a 
   inner join tlmk_id b on a.id_loja = b.id_loja 
   order by id_cliente;
```

Resultado:

```
id_cliente  id_loja ag_tlmk
10  050 0001
10  050 0002
10  050 0003
20  050 0003
20  050 0002
20  050 0001
30  050 0001
30  050 0002
30  050 0003
40  050 0003
40  050 0002
40  050 0001
50  050 0001
50  050 0002
50  050 0003
60  050 0003
60  050 0002
60  050 0001
70  050 0001
70  050 0002
70  050 0003
80  050 0003
80  050 0002
80  050 0001
90  050 0001
90  050 0002
90  050 0003
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma solução

```
USE [MASTER]
GO


CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [dbo].[RANDNUMBERS]
/*
    https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/20/sql-server-using-rand-in-user-defined-functions-udf/
*/
AS
SELECT RAND() 'RAND'
GO

CREATE OR ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[UTIL_GET_RANDNUMBERS]
(
     @MINIMO INT
    ,@MAXIMO INT
)
/*
    https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/20/sql-server-using-rand-in-user-defined-functions-udf/
*/
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ( SELECT @MINIMO + FLOOR([RAND] * (@MAXIMO + 1 - @MINIMO)) FROM [DBO].[RANDNUMBERS] )
END
GO


;WITH LOJA_TB ( [ID_CLIENTE],[ID_LOJA] ) 
AS
(
    SELECT [ID_CLIENTE],[ID_LOJA]  
    FROM ( VALUES (10,'050'),(20,'050'),(30,'050'),(40,'050')
                 ,(50,'050'),(60,'050'),(70,'050'),(80,'050')
                 ,(90,'050') ) AS TAB( [ID_CLIENTE],[ID_LOJA] )
)
, TLMK_ID ( [ID_LOJA],[AG_TLMK] ) 
AS
(
    SELECT [ID_LOJA],[AG_TLMK]
    FROM ( VALUES ('050','0001'),('050','0002')
                 ,('050','0003') ) AS TAB ( [ID_LOJA],[AG_TLMK]) 
)
, TAB_1
AS
(
    SELECT  
         A.ID_CLIENTE
        ,A.ID_LOJA
        ,B.QTDE
    FROM LOJA_TB A 
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(T.[AG_TLMK]) AS 'QTDE'
        FROM TLMK_ID T
        WHERE T.ID_LOJA = A.ID_LOJA 
    ) B

)
, TAB_LOJA_RAND
AS
(
    SELECT 
         T.ID_CLIENTE
        ,T.ID_LOJA
        ,[dbo].[UTIL_GET_RANDNUMBERS](1, T.QTDE) AS 'RAND'
    FROM TAB_1 T
) 
, TAB_TLMK_ID
AS
(
    SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T.ID_LOJA, T.AG_TLMK) AS 'SEQ'
         ,T.ID_LOJA
         ,T.AG_TLMK
    FROM TLMK_ID T

)
SELECT 
      A.ID_CLIENTE
     ,A.ID_LOJA
     --,A.[RAND]
     ,B.AG_TLMK
FROM TAB_LOJA_RAND A
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM TAB_TLMK_ID T 
    WHERE T.ID_LOJA = A.ID_LOJA
    AND T.SEQ = A.[RAND]
) B
```